# Why can't I make a comparison between a variable and enum (C#)

Tags: c#, enums

My reference code:

```
uint bk = 0;
enum ButtonKey : uint
{
   None = 0,
   Key1,
   Key2
};

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bk = (uint)ButtonKey.Key1;
}

void foo()
{
    if( bk == ButtonKey.Key1 )
    {
        // so something
    }
}
```

I get an error on the `bk == ButtonKey.Key1` comparison.  No matter how I try to cast the two, I cannot get beyond this.  I'm sure there is a simple explanation... that is determined to elude me all day!

What am I missing here??  Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried casting the enum to a uint?  `if (bk == (uint)ButtonKey.Key1)`

Comment: Why have you declared `bk` to be of type `uint` to start with? Why not `ButtonKey`?

Comment: I thought this failed.  Retried and of course it worked.  >_<

Comment: Alternatively just make your `bk` variable a `ButtonKey` type. Unless there's a reason not to (and I suspect since you have given the enum an explicit type there's a reason)

Comment: Jon ... didn't know you could do this in C# (I am very new to C#).  That's great.  Thanks for the quick feedback.  +1 to you all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're comparing a `uint` to a particular type of `enum`eration. Cast the enumeration when comparing:

```
if( bk == (uint)ButtonKey.Key1 )
{
    // so something
}
```

A better solution would be to change the type of `bk`:

```
ButtonKey bk;
enum ButtonKey
{
   None = 0,
   Key1,
   Key2
};

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bk = ButtonKey.Key1;
}

void foo()
{
    if( bk == ButtonKey.Key1 )
    {
        // so something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to cast the enum to the representative int value and than you can compare it

```
if(bk == (uint) ButtonKey.Key1)
{

}
```

Comment: ... I'm so ashamed.  I thought I had tried this and it failed.  Thank you, this is what it was.